# Iterating through two arrays using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm in the process of trying to teach myself lambda expressions in C# and I've seem to have stumped myself...

This is essentially what I am trying to accomplish, please assume that ar1 & ar2 will always have the same length.

```
    double sum = 0;

    for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
        sum += (ar1[x]*ar2[x]);
    }
```

Notice the Arrays are being multiplied.

Is there an Lambda function that can accomplish this in a single line?

Thank you

Comment: Suppose you had to invent a method that took a lambda and two sequences; could you write such a method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double sum = ar1.Zip(ar2, (a1, a2) => a1 * a2).Sum();
```

[Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) - applies lambda to corresponding elements of two sequences

[Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) - computes sum of results

Comment: I mean it works -- can walk me through "ar1.zip(ar2, (a1, a2) +> a1*a2)"? .... pretend Im a total noob and have no idea what's going on (pretend)...

Comment: @Nefariis well, what Zip does - it gets enumerators of both sequences and starts enumerating them simultaneously. I.e. each time it calls `MoveNext` on both sequences. On each step we have two `Current` values (a1 and a2). And on each step Zip applies lambda function which accepts these two current values and produces some result. In our case lambda produces multiplication of two `Current` values. Result of multiplication is yielded. So actually Zip produces sequence of multiplications of corresponding items.

Comment: wait, I think Im seeing it -- you are creating another array with a1 and a2 zipped. Then saying that the indices (a1,a2) will be multiplied  => a1*a2 - and then you are just summing it up at the end... Clever - here I was trying to iterate through each one

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a feeling this will come in handy

Comment: Linq is divine ;-)

Comment: @Nefariis `zip` extension method is even more powerful as it will not fail even if your arrays differ in length. e.g.  if `ar1` has 10 elements and `ar2` has 15 elements then final output will product 10 zipped elements and then produce its sum.